# How can you package CouchDB with a OS X Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, macos, couchdb

I'm thinking about making a Cocoa app (desktop) that includes a CouchDB database. How would one go about packaging this in the application bundle so people can install it just like any other Mac OS X app?

Comment: The best way nowadays should be :
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our Mac distribution CouchDBX (http://www.couchone.com/get#mac) is a Cocoa application that bundles CouchDB. To that end, CouchDB and all its dependencies are compiled into a single folder inside the Resources folder of the application bundle. Getting the details of all that right is a bit tricky, so I wrote a script (yay me): https://github.com/janl/couchdbx-core

When run, in produces a folder you can drop into your Resources folder. See https://github.com/janl/couchdbx-app for how launch CouchDB from inside Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

I think [couchobjc](https://github.com/objectiveous/couchobjc) does this without having to install/distribute anything.

Comment: From looking at the FAQ, it looks like doing this is permitted. I'm asking a technical question, though. Are you suggesting that packaging CouchDB in an OSX app is forbidden?

Comment: ( Curses at self. ) I believe the question subject tinted my reading of the body. Sorry about that.